# Understanding Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

In order to tackle real analysis, most of the answers I’ve come across talk about studying from baby rudin. What should be the sequence/order of chapters which one should follow to have a concise understanding.

Comment: Just go in order. Skip the chapter on differential forms.

Comment: I recommend the books Analysis I and Analysis II by Terence Tao. But if you still insist on Rudin, do all chapters in order except chapters 8 and 9. Those are regarded as rather "weak".

Comment: And the reason I recommend Tao over Rudin is because I personally consider Rudin to not be suited for self studies. I rather see Rudin as very good notes on basic analysis. Whereas Tao I consider much more "pedagocical".

Comment: I'm self-studying Rudin right now, along with Abbott's "Understanding Analysis". Abbott teaches the topics in Chapters 2 and 3 of Rudin's book in reverse order. So it was interesting to see the proofs for theorems in both books constructed differently and then relating them. So I found studying the corresponding topics in Abbott's and then Rudin's  book helpful. Although Rudin covers more topics in the book overall.

Comment: @dylan7 interesting way to go about it, how can you manage both of them simultaneously considering the difference in treatment, one being discursive and the other being concise

Comment: @dylan7 also how do you go about studying both of them. Do you first read a chapter from abbott then rudin or sectionwise? Please elucidate

Comment: @brongulus So I should of added that I can only really say this works for the first three chapters of Rudin's book. I'm not sure how much chapter 4 in both books, on continuity will differ. I first did chapters 1, 2 and 3 in Abbott's book, and then 2, and 3 (currently working on exercises in 3) of Rudin's book. But I was planning on continuing doing the chapter in Abbott first and then the corresponding one in Rudin with the same overall topic (functional limits in Abbott, continuity in Rudin).

Comment: I think this worked mostly because Abbott's book explained series so well, and asking the reading to prove some of the theorems that Rudin just proved for the reader. So in some sense I found Rudin's exercises (especially chapter 2) easier, since he also gave a lot more hints in the exercises than Abbott did. Overall, I felt it was the narrow scope of Abbott's book just focusing on the Real numbers, that made it easier to understand Rudin's generalizations to the complex numbers and general metric spaces. I had read about this approach, using a companion book while using Rudin's, somewhere.

Comment: This approach will probably fail for the chapters on integration; I dont think Abbott devotes a lot of time to the Lebesgue measure, if any at all. So if you have any advice/suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: @dylan7 thank you for clarifying, I’ll surely keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to continue with Rudin, you will probably find Francis Su's YouTube series on real analysis very helpful, as he follows that text. You can find it [here](http://analysisyawp.blogspot.com/)